# How to sent results of request to client browser in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to send the results of the following 'request' to the client browser, and don't know how to do it. The function is performed at the Node.js server.

```
var request = require("request");
function RedirectReceiver(url, currentState, callback){
    ; Send url and get back an HTML page
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        // body contains HTML page. Sent it to client browser
    });
};
```

Comment: Unless you have a webSocket connection with the browser, you can only send things to the browser as part of a request when the browser is requesting something from your server and you are sending a response.  So, you need to show us that part of the context of your code for us to have any idea how to advise you.

Comment: I do use (socket.io) for a webSocket in a different part of my app. 
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    // ******** Web Socket Connection ********
    // Used to send information to the Please Wait page when Download in progress
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

Can I force the server to send a ‘/auth’ to itself as if it was done from the client? This ‘/auth’ page is a blank page that I would then send the saved file (body) from?
If not, then how could I use a socket.emit to send the body page back to the client?
 Thanks,
Pat

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  Please outline the exact sequence of events that describe your situation.  What event happens first that triggers your desire to send something to the client?  Is there a request from the client?  If so, then please show the code for that request handler.  If not, then show the code that starts this event and shows how you know which client you want to send to.  Your question needs more explanation before we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The client is on a page and selects a function to download files from their OneDrive cloud service. I am using CloudRail to read these files. When I call the CloudRail function to get files from the clients OneDrive service, CloudRail calls my RedirectReceiver function with a url of OneDrive’s Oauth2 authorization Server.

Comment: I used the “request(url, function(error, response, body) {“ to request a authorization page, which MS OneDrive sent back. I now need to send this page to the client to have them read it and accept or reject it. I want to send this page as a “new” page for them to accept or reject. And then this new page will go away and they will be back on the original download page.

Comment: This whole thing must be driven by the original route that first receives a page request or ajax call from the browser (the action that starts this sequence).  You would have to show that code for us to have any idea how to help.

Comment: This started off at the Server with: app.get('/init_download', function (req, res) {

Comment: @ jfriend00, I can handle this problem from here. Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the client a file, by using `res.sendFile(__dirname + "Your file name");` when the client connect.

For it example if you want to send a client the `index.html` file when he connects:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    console.log('User has reached the login page.');
});
```

**app** is `var app = require('express')();`

I have made a `console.log('User has reached the login page.')` so I can know when the client connects.